# Sunspot search order_by error - target column is not ordered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, sql-order-by, sunspot-rails

I am implementing a pretty basic Sunspot solr search in Ruby on Rails 3.1. I call search on my Idea model with an order_by argument on a integer column but the result set is not ordered.

Search statement in controller.rb:

```
@search = Idea.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  order_by :num_users_joined, :desc
end
@idea_search_res = @search.results
```

Search spec in Idea.rb:

```
searchable do
  text :text
  integer :num_users_joined
end
```

When I iterate through the @idea_search_res result set and print out num_users_joined, I get something like [4,2,3,1].

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem went away. I was running Sunspot on Ubuntu 10.04 in VMWare inside of Windows 7. OS Inception!

I just setup dual boot on Ubuntu 11.10 and Sunspot search order works fine. I don't know what the difference was.